# Xcode 7: Unable to find sample codes in documentation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

earlier xcode versions had code samples for all classes and methods as shown below. But I can't find them in xCode anymore. Does anyone know how to access these in the Apple documentation?

Comment: I'm reading a guide on Objective-C meant for Xcode 6, and it also refers to sample code in the documentation. I've got Xcode 8.3 and it seems to be gone.